# Using "target" to indicate a goal

Tags: word-usage

I want to use the word "target" in a sentence to indicate performing according to the goal/standard.

Please critique my sentences below.

1. We have been shipping to target.
2. We have been shipping to the targeted quantity.
3. We have been shipping at the target speed.
4. We have been performing against the target.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1 is fine.

2 would be better as one of:

- > We have been shipping the targeted quantity.
- > We have been shipping at least the targeted quantity.
- > We have been shipping more than the targeted quantity.

This is because one does not **ship to** a quantity, one just **ships** a quantity.

3 is acceptable, but could also be one of:

- > We have been shipping at the targeted speed.
- > We have been shipping at the targeted rate.

4 is awkward as it stands. It could be phrased as

- > We have been performing at targeted level.
- > We have been measuring our performance against the target.

This is because one does not "perform against" something, one "measures against" something.